# No errors in this PHP script, but does not fill in SQL database

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I really don't know whats going on with this, I've been racking my brain over it for two solid hours. All I am trying to do is get information from two fields in a form and insert it into a database.  I know my script is very basic and very insecure, but I'm just learning... it won't be used on a production site. It lets me submit the data, and outputs the "Thank you, you have registered...", but it never inserts it into the database.  I've double checked all my connection settings, etc... I'm clueless.

My code is below:

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME") or die(mysql_error()); 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['myusername']."', '".$_POST['mypassword']."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>

<html>
<body> 
<h1>Registered</h1>
<p>Thank you, you have registered - you may now login</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

And here is the form code:

```
<table id="mytable" cellspacing="0">
<FORM name="form1" ACTION="register.php" METHOD=get>
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="ttopl">User Name:</th>
<th scope="col" class="ttopl"><input name="myusername" type="text" size"20"></input>      </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="ttopl">Password:</th>
<th scope="col" class="ttopl"><input name="mypassword" type="text" size"20"></input>    </hd>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="ttopl"></th>
<th scope="col" class="ttopl"><input type="submit" value="Register" class="loginButton">
```

Comment: Does the block inside `if( isset` execute at all? (try to add `echo` there if you're not sure)? And read something like this http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php.

Comment: Are you certain you have error_reporting turned to maximum? Remove the isset for debugging.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection; Anyone can execute arbitrary queries by providing the right values in POST data unless you escape the input with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when concatenating it into the query.

Comment: I added an echo, and it did execute.  Not quite sure whats going on.   And I am aware of the dangers of SQL injection, like I said... it won't be used on a live website.

Comment: var_dump( $_POST ); also the output from mysql_query(.. would be handy

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` is not firing makes sure it is the name attribute and not the id. Posting your form code would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong method in your form:

```
<FORM name="form1" ACTION="register.php" METHOD=get>
```

Change this to:

```
<FORM name="form1" ACTION="register.php" METHOD="POST">
```

By the way, I know that security is not a concern yet, but some things are better done right from the start because it will be harder to change later on. For example:

1. hashing / salting the password
2. using PDO with prepared statements to avoid sql injection

**Edit:** You are also missing the `name` attribute in your html form and you are checking for it in the php file. You need to change the submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="loginButton">
```

But a more solid way to check for a `POST` in php is using:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
```

Comment: Tried that with a few other things in the other answers, still no effect  :-?

Answer (score 0):

1st off that query is primed for an injection attack, I would strongly suggest you have a look at prepared statements.

back to your situation...

add

```
var_dump( mysql_error() );
```

immediately after you query and it should tell you what happened to the query...

Comment: As the OP says, this won't be used in production

Comment: @Paul yes he did but based on the [my] perceived quality of code there is no harm what-so-ever at giving some pointers for when it moves to production code.

Comment: @ sp4rt4n423 didn't have your html in the OP but if the var_dump didn't show that'd be a good indication you didn't hit that code block.

Comment: I added that, and it gave me:  string(0) ""      -  Also, var_dump( $_POST() ); gave me:   array(0) { }

Comment: @sp4rt4n423 suggests it executed OK... try putting backticks around password - I think its a reserved word in mysql  ' INSERT INTO members ( \`username\`, \`password\` ) ... '

Answer (score 0):

The only possible thing that could go wrong here is the "if" statement evaluates to false. If anything else went wrong you would get an SQL error output rather than the "Thank You" page.

So first check if 'submit' is the actual name of the form element and also check if its being set. Also check if you are using POST method to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Zac's answer, your Submit button doesn't have a name at all.  Because of this, `isset($_POST['submit'])` will always be false and your query will never run.

Since you're just getting acquainted with PHP, an easy thing you can do to debug situations like this is to use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to inspect your variables.  If you look at $_POST and see that it doesn't have a key named 'submit', you would realize that your submission test is flawed.